# Return value of PowerShell's String.Replace

Tags: powershell, return-value

Consider:

```
$str = 'My {token} string'

$newStr = $str.Replace('{token}', 'value')
$newStr
My value string

function strReplace ($str, $rval) { $str.Replace('{token}', $rval) }
$newStr = strReplace($str, 'value')
$newStr
My  string
value
```

Even though `string.Replace` returns a single string, an `object[]` shows up in the return pipeline. Why? Is there a way to get the obvious return value?

Comment: when I run this code, it get an error with the following line:
$newStr = strReplace($str, 'value')
but when I replace it with:
$newStr = strReplace $str 'value'
it works as expected. I'm using Powershell 2.0 with .net 4.0

Comment: maybe it is a change with ps3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are passing in an array as the argument for `$str` in your function. You need to call PowerShell functions like this (no brackets, no commas separating arguments):

```
$newStr = strReplace $str 'value'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same object[] even after removing the parentheses.  I'm using ps3 on Win8.

Comment: Did you remember to drop the comma too? spaces are used to seperate arguments